# Secure way to encrypt a string in android, even if the project is decompiled?

Tags: android, encryption

I need to Encrypt some string data in my android app using a secure encryption algorithm. We know that a secure encryption system does not hide the encryption algorithm, it hides the key; But it's possible to decompile an android app using tools like [javadecompilers](http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk), so no matter what algorithm I use, it's always possible that somebody decompiles my app, finds my key and accesses my data!

Is what I think correct? And if so, what is the solution?

Comment: Who are you trying to hide the data from?

Comment: It is not possible to hide a key in a program so that no one can obtain it, what can be accomplished is rot raise the work factor high enough that only a few with great effort can obtain it. This is why DRM solutions rely on an authentication server.

Comment: One way you can store the key in server and get it via api call & using that key make encryption of string & store the encrpted value locally in device.

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH: Whatever the app can do the user can do. Or the user can watch the app do it and copy the key the app gets.

Comment: @JamesKPolk From anyone other than user and server. I'm using https with certificate pinning and I'm sure no body can access my data when transmitting but i have some worries about my app being decompiled.

Comment: @zaph You're right. Do you have any particular solution?

Comment: There is not way to both encrypt the data on the client and not protect the key 100% if the key is in the app. The device owner has full access to the device. Not enough information is provided own what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the Natvie implementation of the Rob Napier's RNCryptor which you can find here: https://github.com/TGIO/RNCryptorNative

And store the key in a secure way as described here: https://rammic.github.io/2015/07/28/hiding-secrets-in-android-apps/